# NPE in DebugPlugin.getDefault()

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, launch-configuration

I've got the following piece of code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin;
import org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfigurationType;
import org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy;
import org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchManager;
import org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String... strings) throws IOException {
        try {
            String path = "E:\\Java\\Projects\\.metadata\\.plugins\\org.eclipse.debug.core\\.launches\\MedicineFrame.launch";

            ILaunchManager launchManager = DebugPlugin.getDefault()
                    .getLaunchManager();
            ILaunchConfigurationType type = launchManager
                    .getLaunchConfigurationType(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE);
            ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy workingCopy = type.newInstance(
                    null, path);
            workingCopy.setAttribute("PATH_MY", path);
            ILaunchConfiguration configuration = workingCopy.doSave();
            DebugUITools.launch(configuration, ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE);
        } catch (CoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }}
```

Actually, I just want to run the launch configuration specified in the file defined by absolute path.
I receive an NPE, because the DebugPlugin.getDefault() returns null. What should I do? I've found a lot of similar examples, but none of them tells about the NPE, like no one has ever got it before me.

Comment: Are you sure that `DebugPlugin.getDefault()` really returns `null`? Please try debugging this (again?) first.

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure if it's the only code in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quick look at DebugPlugin [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5/org.eclipse.debug/core/3.5.0/org/eclipse/debug/core/DebugPlugin.java#DebugPlugin.0fgDebugPlugin) I found that `DebugPlugin#getDefault()` method is simple getter to `fgDefaultPlugin` field, and return this field value which is `null` by default. Since you're invoking `DebugPlugin#getDefault()` as very first method of your `main` function it's reasonable that it returns `null`, since `DebugPlugin#setDefault()` was not previously called.

You can't run Eclipse from a main method like that. You need to write a plugin, and it will be accesible from inside the plugin method.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to create a plugin - the exception disappears :)